# Getting Operation statistics of CSGO using steam web api

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I want to fetch all Operations' statistics of Counter-Strike: Global Offensive for any user by his/her steam64 ID. I have found an api request url which returns a list of achievements for this user by app id.

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=730&key=<<API KEY>>&steamid=<<STEAM64 ID>>
```

But it doesn't return any operation's statistics as far as i see. Experts, please help me to fetch all Operations' statistics of CSGO.

Answer (score 0):

Achievements and operations are completly different things:

**Achievements** - Virtual badges you get during the game, for every game, triggered by the game itself

**Operations** - Paid set of missions (...), only in CS:GO, triggered by whether you got the operation or not

You can check if somebody took part in an operation by looking in his inventory (there should be a coin/ medal to identify) but the individual stats aren´t accessible by the Web API.

If you still figure out a way to achieve this, please post this here.